# Saving search for future use with form and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a function that I'm using to build my charts:

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    drawChart(start_date, end_date, type, unit) 
}); 

function drawChart(start_date, end_date, type, unit) {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        //url: "server.php?start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date + "&type=" + type,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);
    (...)
```

Is there a way to save my charts search based on these parameters: `start_date`, `end_date`, `type` which are obtained from a form? I want to save every search that user does while they are logged in.

Comment: Where do you want to store the queries? Database or local machine?

Comment: Local machine, maybe Session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this can get you started:

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    var tempArr = new Array();
    var json = window.sessionStorage['search'];
    if(json)
        tempArr = JSON.parse(json);
    tempArr.push(JSON.parse('{"start_date" : "'+start_date+'" , "end_date" : "'+end_date+'" , "type" : "'+type+'"}'));
    window.sessionStorage['search'] = JSON.stringify(tempArr);
    drawChart(start_date, end_date, type, unit) 
});
```

Next time when your user login, get the search_details from window.sessionStorage['search'].
WHen you want to see the history of searches, you can use JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage['search']); and it will give you an array of objects which you can pass to server side processing.

Comment: Sekhran, how can i see what is inside of window.sessionStorage['search'] now ?

Comment: `["{\"start_date\" : \"2012-11-01\" , \"end_date\" : \"2012-11-22\" , \"type\" : \"pie\"}","{\"start_date\" : \"2012-11-01\" , \"end_date\" : \"2012-11-22\" , \"type\" : \"pie\"}"]` How can I use that for a future use?

Comment: I'm testing this right now. I should be able to "click" in one of those saved searchs and do something. So, I need that `start_date`, `end_date` and `type` separated to get them in `drawChart(start_date, end_date, type)`. Am I explaining well?